# Perform operation on elements of array within an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to find the sum of the products of two elements where each element is in its own separate object. AKA I am trying to find TotalValue where:

**TotalValue = Sum[Arrays.close * List.amtPurch]**

The Arrays object is pulled from an API so its in this funky format where it appears each array is nested one level too deep. That's where I am having trouble accessing each element to do the above operation

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
Arrays =
[
    [
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "minute": "12:34",
            "label": "12:34 PM",
            "high": 123.37,
            "low": 123.3,
            "open": 123.36,
            "close": 123.31,
            "average": 123.338,
            "volume": 1519,
            "notional": 187351.33,
            "numberOfTrades": 16
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "minute": "12:34",
            "label": "12:34 PM",
            "high": null,
            "low": null,
            "open": null,
            "close": null,
            "average": null,
            "volume": 0,
            "notional": 0,
            "numberOfTrades": 0
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "minute": "12:34",
            "label": "12:34 PM",
            "high": 676.5,
            "low": 675.41,
            "open": 676.21,
            "close": 675.41,
            "average": 675.977,
            "volume": 1353,
            "notional": 914597.545,
            "numberOfTrades": 38
       }
    ]
]

List: [
                { tick: "AAPL", amtPurch: 50, purchPrice: 10, datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "GOOG", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "TSLA", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
       ]
```

Comment: You can use flat() to get rid of wrapping array, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arrays =
[
    [
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "minute": "12:34",
            "label": "12:34 PM",
            "high": 123.37,
            "low": 123.3,
            "open": 123.36,
            "close": 123.31,
            "average": 123.338,
            "volume": 1519,
            "notional": 187351.33,
            "numberOfTrades": 16
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "minute": "12:34",
            "label": "12:34 PM",
            "high": null,
            "low": null,
            "open": null,
            "close": null,
            "average": null,
            "volume": 0,
            "notional": 0,
            "numberOfTrades": 0
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "date": "2021-04-01",
            "minute": "12:34",
            "label": "12:34 PM",
            "high": 676.5,
            "low": 675.41,
            "open": 676.21,
            "close": 675.41,
            "average": 675.977,
            "volume": 1353,
            "notional": 914597.545,
            "numberOfTrades": 38
       }
    ]
];

const list = [
                { tick: "AAPL", amtPurch: 50, purchPrice: 10, datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "GOOG", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "TSLA", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
       ];
       
const result = arrays.reduce((acc, val, index) => acc + val[0].close * list[index].amtPurch, 0)

console.log(result);
```